# Android Data Binding

Tags: android, kotlin

How to set a default value for an Observable Field of type Boolean

```
@Bindable
    var buttonEnabled: ObservableField<Boolean> = ObservableField()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow, you can set it as follows:

```
@Bindable
    var buttonEnabled: ObservableField<Boolean> = ObservableField(true)
```

It is false by default.